# Bazel rules with unknown output filenames

Tags: bazel

I have a command that compiles and runs a program, but the intermediate files are randomly named (but contained within a directory). E.g.

```
build foo.src bar.src -o output_dir
run output_dir
```

Bazel requires me to pre-declare all of the outputs of my rule, but I can't do that because they're randomly named. Can I somehow name an entire directory instead?

The only alternative I can think of is having the rule zip/unzip the directory before/after it runs the commands, which is a pretty awful solution.

Edit: I found an issue exactly describing the "just zip/unzip everything" solution [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2414). [The closing comment](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2414#issuecomment-541441484) says to just use the rules from [rules_pkg](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg) to zip/unzip stuff. Unfortunately it requires Python too.

Some of the comments in that thread suggest you can use [`declare_directory()`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/actions#declare_directory) but I don't think that really works.

Comment: Why doesn't `declare_directory` work?

Comment: Good question - I did get an error but I think I was using it wrong. I tried again and it works, thanks! I think probably the issue was I was trying to use it as an input and an output (one of the processes just modifies it) and maybe that can't work.

Answer (score 3):

There are tree artifacts. An example of how to use a tree artifact can be found [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/main/core_principles/tree_artifact).
Tree artifacts are problematic for caching since Bazel is not aware of the content of the corresponding directory and if for some reason the content of a tree artifact is different between two machines that use the same Bazel cache and same Bazel configuration you are in trouble.

Comment: Does it not hash the directory contents?